# Third Party URL not logging in to account in Ionic iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, cordova-plugin-advanced-http

I am using Cordova Plugin Advance HTTP to fetch the user token from my server and then create a url from that token to let my current user sign in to his account profile. My code is as below:

**teetime.page.ts**

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.callCloudFunction().then( data => {
    this.urlSafe= this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
    this.canRender = true;
    });
}

async callCloudFunction() {
    var memberTokenUrl = 'https://www.example.com/WebResAPI/Api/User/GetNewUserTokenByMemberNumber?authToken=&userToken=' + token + '&clubFriendlyName=MyClub&memberNumber='

    var memberToken = await this.getMemberToken(memberTokenUrl);
    console.log("Member Token: " + memberToken);

    //Create Login URL
    this.url = 'https://www.example.com/WebRes/Club/MyClub/LoginWithToken/' + memberToken;
    console.log("Login URL: " + this.url);

    //Hide Loading Container
    await this.loading.dismiss();

    return this.url;
}

//Get Member Token
getMemberToken(memberTokenUrl){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.get(memberTokenUrl, {}, {})
    .then(data => {
        var memberTok = JSON.parse(data.data).Value ;
        resolve(memberTok);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.error);
    });
    });
}
```

**teetimes.page.html**

```
<ion-content>
  <div style="overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch" *ngIf="canRender">
      <iframe [src]="urlSafe" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

**ios console log**

[Log] Member Token: 4PHZjQUkGETmF4M9lm7TppjoMhwqHudyhjRGZmyBxY7gCTEgazGIKWekRRLo (cordova.98fc7fcb7c020c1504f6.js, line 1)
[Log] Login URL: https://www.example.com/WebRes/Club/MyClub/LoginWithToken/4PHZjQUkGETmF4M9lm7TppjoMhwqHudyhjRGZmyBxY7gCTEgazGIKWekRRLo (cordova.98fc7fcb7c020c1504f6.js, line 1)

I am able to successfully get the token from my server and am able to form the URL as well successfully but the problem here is this formed URL with user token logs me in perfectly in my android device but it is not opening my user account in iOS. I am able to see all logs perfectly in iOS and I am able to get the token and form the url but what it does is, it takes me to the logged out home page instead of showing me my logged in account.

However, if I click on the login URL from my console log, it does takes me to my logged in user account in Safari.

Any idea what am I doing wrong here? It does works perfectly in Android though and it does log me in automatically to my user account but this is not working in iOS and it takes me to homepage of my website instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use instead of iframe, **InAppBrowser** native plugin to open websites without leaving the app?

[In App Browser - Tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser)

**Commands installation:**

```
> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
> npm install @ionic-native/in-app-browser
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Why InAppBrowser instead of iFrames?**

From Cordova docs:
*The InAppBrowser window behaves like a standard web browser, and can't access Cordova APIs. For this reason, **the InAppBrowser is recommended if you need to load third-party (untrusted) content**, instead of loading that into the main Cordova webview. The InAppBrowser is not subject to the whitelist, nor is opening links in the system browser.*

**NOTE:** Plugin is implemented via iframe.

Comment: While it does work perfectly in inappbrowser as desired but the I want that url to open inside my app. The target option "_blank" opens on top of app as a kind of popup. Any idea, why it is logging me in with my url in inappbrowser and is not working in iframe??? iframe does work perfectly in Android though.

Comment: @Kartik By default, navigations only to file:// URLs, are allowed. To allow others URLs, you must add tags to your config.xml: 
<allow-navigation href="*" />

Additionally, keep mind that:_self: Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser. _blank: Opens in the InAppBrowser. And _system: Opens in the system's web browser.

Comment: @KartikSolanki More explanation added to original answer.

Best regards.